# Is it bad to use ALTER TABLE to resize a varchar column to a larger size?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a simple resize of a column from `VARCHAR(36)` to `VARCHAR(40)`.

If you try to use SQL Server Enterprise Manager, the script it generates is effectively creating a new table with the new structure, inserting all of the data from the existing table into it, dropping the existing table, renaming the new table, and recreating any indexes.

If you read the documentation (and many online resources including SO), you can use an `ALTER` statement for the resize.

Does the `ALTER` affect the way the data is stored in any way?  Indexes?  Statistics?  I want to avoid performance hits because of this modification due to the fact that the table can get large.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use ALTER TABLE. SSMS is a bit, er, stupid sometimes

You'll need to drop and recreate dependent constraints (FK, unique, index, check etc)

However, this is only a metadata change and will be very quick for any size table (unless you also change NOT NULL to NULL or varchar to nvarchar or such)

Comment: Won't this move the field to the end of the rows on the pages though?  I thought it could create pointers and page splits.

Comment: @JNK: nah. no data movement will happen because none is needed

Comment: @JNK This is exactly why I was asking the question, but it seems as though it's not true.

Comment: @gbn is of course correct.  With variable length's its a meta change, with `CHAR` it would have other effects.

Comment: @gbn, congrats on reaching 100k.

Answer (score 5):

No, `ALTER TABLE` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms190273.aspx) is the way how Microsoft intended to do this kind of change.

And if you do not add extra options to your command, no indexes or statistics should get harmed.
A possibility of data loss is also not given, because you are just making the column bigger.
Everything should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Changes to database structure should NEVER be made using SSMS on a porduction environment for just the reason you brought up. It can destroy performance in a large table. ALTER  table is the prefered method, it is faster and it can be stored in source control as a change to push to prod after testing.

Comment: You can use SSMS to *run the SQL DDL script* - can't you? :-)

Comment: yes. I did phse that wqrong, you shoudln't use the GUI to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Following should be the better way to handle this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT   1 
               FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE    TABLE_NAME = '<tablename>' 
               AND      COLUMN_NAME = '<field>')
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN [<field>] varchar(xxxx) null
    END
ELSE
```